# Cannot GET /chatroom

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, socket.io

I am new here. 
I am trying to develop a web application and I have hit a brick wall which I've been stuck on for a while now.

When running my app.js file all pages show up except for the chatroom. Could someone please take a look at the code and help me out?

I haven't included my code for register and login etc. as they are working fine. When using their router.get and .post concepts for the chatroom I just receive a "Cannot GET /chatroom" message.

Chatroom.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const socketClient = require('socket.io').listen(4000).sockets;


//Chatroom page: Credit - Traversy Media - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hrRue5Rt6Is&t=1542s
router.get('/chatroom', (req, res) => res.render('chatroom.ejs'));

router.post('/chatroom', (req, res) => {

// Connect to Socket.io
socketClient.on('connection', function (socket) {
    let chat = db.collection('UsersDB/chats');

    // Create function to send status
    sendStatus = function (s) {
        useUnifiedTopology: true,
        socket.emit('status', s);
    }

    // Get chats from mongo collection
    chat.find().limit(100).sort({ _id: 1 }).toArray(function (err, res) {
        if (err) {
            throw err;
        }

        // Emit the messages
        socket.emit('output', res);
    });

    // Handle input events
    socket.on('input', function (data) {
        let name = data.name;
        let message = data.message;

        // Check for name and message
        if (name == '' || message == '') {
            // Send error status
            sendStatus('Please enter a name and message');
        } else {
            // Insert message
            chat.insert({ name: name, message: message }, function () {
                socketClient.emit('output', [data]);

                // Send status object
                sendStatus({
                    message: 'Message sent',
                    clear: true
                });
            });
        }
    });

    // Handle clear
    socket.on('clear', function (data) {
        // Remove all chats from collection
        chat.remove({}, function () {
            // Emit cleared
            socket.emit('cleared');
            });
        });
    });

});
```

app.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const expressLayouts = require('express-ejs-layouts');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const passport = require('passport');
const flash = require('connect-flash');
const session = require('express-session');


const app = express();

// Passport Config
require('./config/passport')(passport);

// DB Config
const db = require('./config/keys').mongoURI;

// Connect to MongoDB
mongoose
  .connect(
    db,
    { useNewUrlParser: true }
  )
  .then(() => console.log('MongoDB Connected'))
  .catch(err => console.log(err));

// EJS
app.use(expressLayouts);
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

// Express body parser
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

// Express session
app.use(
  session({
    secret: 'secret',
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true
  })
);

// Passport middleware
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

// Connect flash
app.use(flash());

// Global variables
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.locals.success_msg = req.flash('success_msg');
  res.locals.error_msg = req.flash('error_msg');
  res.locals.error = req.flash('error');
  next();
});

// Routes
app.use('/', require('./routes/index.js'));
app.use('/users', require('./routes/users.js'));
app.use('/chatroom', require('./routes/chatroom.js'));

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.listen(PORT, console.log(`Server started on port ${PORT}`));
```

Comment: Is this a top level route? Where/how is this router/file being utilized? Is it exported and used in another file to register the route? If yes, can we please see some some more code for further context?

Comment: Thank you for your reply Thomas! Yes what I showed was the chatroom.js file which I am calling again in the app.js (which I run) with app.use('/chatroom', require('./routes/chatroom.js')); - I have done the same with login and register and they work fine.

Comment: I think because you are already specifying the route to be '/chatroom' , you don't need to explicitly specify it in chatroom.js. Change the `router.get('/chatroom')` to `router.get('/')`. I think it will work.

Comment: Did you try `/chatroom/chatroom`? I thinks you should have `router.get('/')`

Answer (score 0):

First and foremost I'd like to thank Cranky Coder; Prakher Londe; and Sunil Lulla for your replies.

I ended up figuring out how to make the chatroom show up. As mentioned before my other pages(login and register etc.) were showing up fine. Unlike the chatroom I had the backend for these in a users.js file. So what I decided to do was move my chatroom.js code into my users.js which was then called in the app.js(the file I run) with app.use('/users', require('.routes/users.js')).

I then changed my router.get code to:

```
router.get('/chatroom', (req, res) => res.render('chatroom', {
  user: req.user
}));
```

Then in my router.post (see OP for context) I added a res.redirect('/users/chatroom'); before closing with the final bracket.
Lastly I of course edited my .ejs file to have

I found that doing it this way is even better because the chatroom cannot be accessed unless one is logged in.

Thank you again for all your replies and although this is a bit of a specific problem I do hope this helps someone in the future.